# Jquery - Remove Particular String from String and return new string

Tags: jquery, string, split

I have the following string:

```
var my_fruits = "Apples, Bananas, Mangos, Blackberries, Oranges";
```

I want to remove "Mangos" (or any other fruit by giving a name) so that the new string would look like this:

```
"Apples, Bananas, Blackberries, Oranges".
```

How can i achieve this with/without JQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a replace using a regular expression:

```
myFruits = myFruits.replace(/\bMangos(, |$)/gi, "");
```

The `\b` will match a word boundary.
The `(, |$)` will match either a `,`  or the end of the string.

Comment: This doesn't really suit the "or any other fruit by giving a name" part

Comment: to clarify: the fruit name (which will be removed) is defined from the beginning. how would it be, if I have the variable is "Bananas" instead of "Mangos"?

Comment: @Nick, Steilflug: `new Regex("\\b" + name + "(, |$)", "gi")`

Answer (score 2):

One approach uisng using an array, you can use [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/) to filter an array you create from splitting based on the comma, like this:

```
var my_fruits = "Apples, Bananas, Mangos, Blackberries, Oranges";
var result = $.grep(my_fruits.split(', '), function(v) { return v != "Mangos"; }).join(', ');
alert(result);
```

[You can test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qNFAV/).  Or in function form (since you want to pass in what to filter out):

```
function filterOut(my_str, t) { //string, term
  return $.grep(my_str.split(', '), function(v) { return v != t; }).join(', ');
}
```

[You cant test that version here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/qNFAV/1/).